# Getting a Magento Category to return false

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, magento

I have set up a Magento website and am trying to get one of the top level menu items to `return false` so basically I have it set up as a Category on the top level of the menu system but don't want it to actually go anywhere. I just want the subcategories to be shown when they hover over it, is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a [jQuery Selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and binding a [click() event](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to it.  First, though, you'll need to find the link or some other unique attribute to the menu-item (right-click and inspect element).  For this example, I will assume that the link is `http://www.example.com/return-false` and that it doesn't appear anywhere else on the website:

```
$('[href="http://www.example.com/return-false"]').click(function() {return false;});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtr_webdev/9L9poaqk/)